# Recording Data & Compressing it on the Fly

Tags: c#

I have a server program that reads data from a remote stream via TCP, writes it as binary, and then compress it. Is there anyway to write data directly compressed to gain server storage space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a stream that implements compression, E.G. [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

Comment: Nice. Appearently the FileStream is created on disk, compressed, & gets disposed so it is not persisted. Only the compressed stream is persisted on disk. Do you confirm this ? Thank you

Comment: +1. @Mika Jacobi, your comment is clearly about some of your code that we don't see - hard to confirm it. Compression stream are wrapping stream and can write/read data from any other stream (like FileStream).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : It is the example code in the MSDN link provided in the answer :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does.  If this is the answer can you mark it as such please.  Thx.

Comment: @Mika Jacobi, compression streams classes persist/read data from underlying stream (in case of the MSDN sample FileStream). So final persistence depends on how that underlying stream is persisted - in this case file will be saved when using block for File stream is done.